# How do I set Readonly to buttons and textboxes dynamically?

Tags: c++, winapi

Like while I am initializing the program, I want all my buttons/textboxes to be in a read-only state, but after I'm done they will go back to a clickable state. How can I go about performing this?

Comment: For edits, consider `EM_SETREADONLY` if you still want the user to be able to interact with the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [EnableWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to enable / disable input to a control. If for example you have a button with a handle of `hButton` and an edit with a handle of `hEdit` you can enable the input as follows:

```
EnableWindow(hButton, TRUE);
EnableWindow(hEdit, TRUE);
```

To disable the above controls use:

```
EnableWindow(hButton, FALSE);
EnableWindow(hEdit, FALSE);
```

Comment: The second argument for [EnableWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646291.aspx) is of type `BOOL` with values `TRUE` and `FALSE`. While `bool` can be implicitly converted to `BOOL`, it's still the wrong type.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the info. Updated.